# Rename Firefox Extension Title

Tags: firefox, rename, title

We are trying to rename the title of the Fire Fox Extension. We are getting an unwanted random number before the title of the Extension. Attachment enclosed.

Is there any way to remove or rename this via java script, since it is not very user friendly.

Any help is highly appreciated.
[image: Extension Title needs to be renamed]

Comment: Please provide relevant information in the question, not as an attachment hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Can we rename the Title of the Firefox Extension using java script such that it doesn't contain the random id(as show above in the attachment). Example:-

Valid Title:-
Custom Extension Title

Invalid Title:-
moz-extension://da0dd3345-deaf34...

I tried changing the using document.title and window.title, didn't work out.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards